# Applying a Formula to All Cells in a Column (Even New Cells)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Google Spreadsheets and currently, this is what I have in J2: `=iferror(H2/G2,0)`

I know I can double click the square in the bottom right and it will apply to every cell in the column but if I were to create a new row anywhere in the spreadsheet it would show up as empty.  I just want every cell including Newly created cells to be filled with the formula above so it will display the correct data for that row.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(H2:H)*len(G2:G), iferror(H2:H/G2:G, 0),))
```

The formula will output results if there are entries in col H AND col G.
See if that works for you ?